# How can I create a valid tax rates for all EU countries (2013) in Magento

Tags: php, magento, csv, data-import

How can I a create valid tax rates for all EU countries (2013) in Magento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a CSV tax rates import file for all EU countries based on the DE VAT rate (19%).

(magento_eu_tax_rates.csv)

```
Code,Country,State,Zip/Post Code,Rate,Zip/Post is Range,Range From,Range To,default,germany
AT,AT,*,,19,,,,VAT,
BE,BE,*,,19,,,,VAT,
BG,BG,*,,19,,,,VAT,
HR,HR,*,,19,,,,VAT,
CY,CY,*,,19,,,,VAT,
CZ,CZ,*,,19,,,,VAT,
DK,DK,*,,19,,,,VAT,
EE,EE,*,,19,,,,VAT,
FI,FI,*,,19,,,,VAT,
FR,FR,*,,19,,,,VAT,
DE,DE,*,,19,,,,VAT,
GR,GR,*,,19,,,,VAT,
HU,HU,*,,19,,,,VAT,
IE,IE,*,,19,,,,VAT,
IT,IT,*,,19,,,,VAT,
LV,LV,*,,19,,,,VAT,
LT,LT,*,,19,,,,VAT,
LU,LU,*,,19,,,,VAT,
MT,MT,*,,19,,,,VAT,
NL,NL,*,,19,,,,VAT,
PL,PL,*,,19,,,,VAT,
PT,PT,*,,19,,,,VAT,
RO,RO,*,,19,,,,VAT,
SK,SK,*,,19,,,,VAT,
SI,SI,*,,19,,,,VAT,
ES,ES,*,,19,,,,VAT,
SE,SE,*,,19,,,,VAT,
GB,GB,*,,19,,,,VAT,
```

Comment: What use to me is the German 19% VAT Rate, I'm in the UK where VAT is 20%

Comment: Note that the Magento development team also recommend quoting all values in a tax-rate CSV file - http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tip-importing-tax-rates/

Answer (score 1):

An up to date CSV for EU tax rates in 2014 that works with Magento 1.9.0.1 (note that this is the current UK VAT rate of 20%). It should also be noted that Iceland, Liechtenstein, Norway and Switzerland are exempt from UK VAT.

```
Code,Country,State,Zip/Post Code,Rate,Zip/Post is Range,Range From,Range To,default
GB,GB,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
AL,AL,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
AD,AD,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
AT,AT,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
BY,BY,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
BE,BE,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
BA,BA,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
BG,BG,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
HR,HR,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
CY,CY,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
CZ,CZ,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
DK,DK,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
EE,EE,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
FO,FO,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
FI,FI,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
FR,FR,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
DE,DE,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
GI,GI,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
GR,GR,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
HU,HU,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
IS,IS,*,,0.0000,,,,VAT
IE,IE,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
IT,IT,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
LV,LV,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
LB,LB,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
LI,LI,*,,0.0000,,,,VAT
LT,LT,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
LU,LU,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
MT,MT,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
MD,MD,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
MC,MC,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
ME,ME,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
NL,NL,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
NO,NO,*,,0.0000,,,,VAT
PL,PL,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
PT,PT,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
RO,RO,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
RS,RS,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
SK,SK,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
SI,SI,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
ES,ES,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
SJ,SJ,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
SE,SE,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
CH,CH,*,,0.0000,,,,VAT
TR,TR,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
UA,UA,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
VA,VA,*,,20.0000,,,,VAT
```